# HotTowel - Durandal navigation to view with filter predicate to Breeze as parameter

Tags: breeze, single-page-application, durandal, hottowel

I am not clear how to implement architecture-wise the navigation to a new view with filter predicate as parameter in MVC4 SPA HotTowel template.
Lets say I have a home view with dropdown with dates (filter) and a button "gotoSessions" to navigate to the Sessions view. GoToSessions button will navigate to the Sessions view displaying the sessions for the selected date only. Not selecting a date will force the Sessions View to display all available sessions.

[image: Home View Screen Added]

1. Update the "sessions" route in config.js to accept filter parameter

   ```
   var routes = [{
       url: 'sessions/:filter',
       moduleId: 'viewmodels/sessions',
       name: 'Sessions',
       visible: true,
       caption: '<i class="icon-book"></i> Sessions' }, {... the rest of the routes ..}];
   ```
2. Implement the "gotoSessions" button

   ```
    var selectedDate = ko.observable();

    var gotoSessions = function(viewData) { 
      if (viewData && viewData.selectedDate) {
         // build filter to pass to Breeze QueryManager as where clause
         var filter = viewData.selectedDate.peek();

         // build url with filter parameter
         var url = '#/sessions/' + predicate;

         router.navigateTo(url);
      }
   };
   ```
3. In the sessions.js viewmodel update the activate method to accept routeData as parameter
   and implement filtering in the datacontext.js service

   ```
   var activate = function (context) {
      var filterParam = context.filter;

      // update datacontext getSessionsPartials method to accept filter parameter
      return datacontext.getSessionsPartials(sessions, false, filterParam ); 
   };
   ```
4. In the services/datacontext.js update the query to use the filter

   ```
   var getSpeakersPartials = function (speakersObservable, forceRemote, filter) { 
   //... code ... 
      var query = EntityQuery.from('Speakers')
        .select('id, firstName, lastName, imageSource')
        .where(... filter here ...)
        .orderBy(orderBy.speaker);
        //... rest of the code...
   };

   function getLocal(resource, filtering, ordering) {
      var query;
      if (filtering) {
         query = EntityQuery.from(resource)
              .where('yourPropertyNameHere', 'equals', filtering)
              .orderBy(ordering);
      }
      else {
          query = EntityQuery.from(resource).orderBy(ordering);
      }   
   }
   ```

Is this the correct implementation for the MVC4 SPA HotTowel architecture?
Can you please give code example for the filter (predicate) formating?
Thanks

Comment: Looks like the inline were filter works better in this case than the usage of predicate object.
EntityQuery.fromEntities(customers)
    .where("Region", FilterQueryOp.NotEquals, null);

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an odd user workflow to make the user choose the date then go to the page. Why not go to the sessions page first, then select the dropdown? Same number of clicks and it makes more sense for the user to be on the sessions and then choose the filter. The page could first appear with no sessions (or all with paging). Then select the dropdown and the filter is auto applied.

If you want to pass parameters to a view, you can do that with the :parm syntax in the hash tag querystring, but I think re-thinking the UX is a better option.

Comment: I agree. The question was adapted for the Code Camper example and it doesn't make much sense. Sorry. I really wanted to know how to pass parameters to view.

Comment: Got ya. I mentioned at the bottom of that you can use the :parameter syntax.